# Pass Associative Array as Data Param in POST request using cURL

Tags: bash, shell, curl, post, gitlab-api

I have an **associative array** that I want to pass to cURL as POST data. However i have tried multiple things, still it doesn't work.

The **array**:

```
declare -A details
details[name]="Honey"
details[class]="10"
details[section]="A"
details[subject]="maths"
```

The **cURL commands** have tried so far (*all of these failed*):

```
resp = $(cURL --request POST --data details "https://somedomain.net/getMarks")
resp = $(cURL --request POST --data variables=details "https://somedomain.net/getMarks")
resp = $(cURL --request POST --data "variables=$details" "https://somedomain.net/getMarks") 
resp = $(cURL --request POST --data "variables=${details}" "https://somedomain.net/getMarks") 
resp = $(cURL --request POST --data $details "https://somedomain.net/getMarks") 
resp = $(cURL --request POST --data ${details} "https://somedomain.net/getMarks") 
resp = $(cURL --request POST --data variables=details "https://somedomain.net/getMarks")
```

Something like shown below, I want the above request to be (indirectly), however I want to pass the array directly instead of writing its contents.

```
resp = $(cURL --request POST --data '{"variables":[{"name": "Honey"},{"class": "10"},{"section": "A"},{"subject": "maths"}]}' "https://somedomain.net/getMarks")
```

Please note that to begin with I will always have the associative array ONLY (not any json array or string).

This question rose when I was trying **calling cURL command with the associative array** as on this [link](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/pipelines.html#create-a-new-pipeline) (GITLAB API)(the example *does not contain* variables array example). Here they have mentioned a variables array (array of hashes).

Comment: do the array entries need to be added to the `curl` request in the same order as shown, ie, `name` then `class` then `section` then `subject`? can the array have a varying number of entries and array indices? can either component of an arry entry - index or data - contain newlines?

Comment: no, no need to preserve order of array entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Since I had to use an **older version of bash**, which **does not involve
   the name referencing as stated on the answer**, I had to try to
   code string creation of the associative array without passing it to a function
2. Since I always had an **associative array to begin with**, the process of passing the array as accepted by the gitlab API normally was:

```
resp=$(cURL --request POST --data '{"variables":[{"name": "Honey"},{"class": "10"},{"section": "A"},{"subject": "maths"}]}' "https://somedomain.net/getMarks")
```

OR

```
resp=$(cURL --request POST --data "variables[name]=Honey" --data "variables[class]=10" --data "variables[section]=A" --data "variables[subject]=maths" "https://somedomain.net/getMarks")
```

So tried some tweaks on the second way and what worked for me was:

```
_sep=""
_string=""

for index in "${!details[@]}"
do
    _string="${_string}${_sep}variables[${index}]="${details[$index]}"
    _sep="&"
done

resp=$(cURL --request POST --data "$_string" "https://somedomain.net/getMarks")

#which indirectly was:
resp=$(cURL --request POST --data "variables[name]=Honey&variables[class]=10&variables[section]=A&variables[subject]=maths" "https://somedomain.net/getMarks")
```

And it was a success. Thanks to @markp-fuso for giving me an intuition of creating a string with his logic above.

Answer (score 0):

Assumptions/understandings:

- no need to list the array entries in any particular order
- neither the array indices or values contain newlines

One `bash` idea:

```
# use a function to build the --data component

build_data() {
    local -n _arr="$1"                       # use nameref so we can pass in the name of any associative array
    local    _sep=""
    local    _string='{"variables":['
    local    _i

    for i in "${!_arr[@]}"
    do
        _string="${_string}${_sep}{\"${i}\": \"${_arr[$i]}\"}"
        _sep=","
    done

    printf "%s]}" "${_string}"
}
```

Adding this to the `curl` call:

```
resp=$(cURL --request POST --data "$(build_data details)" "https://somedomain.net/getMarks")
```

**NOTES:**

- no spaces allowed on either side of the `=`, ie, `resp = $(curl ...)` needs to be `resp=$(curl ...)`
- without an actual/valid URL I'm guessing a bit on if/where the escaped quotes belong so may need to tweak the escaped quotes to get working correcly

Comment: didn't understand this comment: # use nameref so we can pass in the name of any associative array

Comment: when calling the function we pass the *name* of the array, eg, `build_data details`; if you happen to name your array something else (eg, `new_details`) then the function call becomes `build_data new_details`; the `nameref` just allows us to map any array name you may have to local name of `_arr` ... this way the function does not need to be manually edited to reference whatever name your real array i

Comment: Can you update your answer as per the edit i made in the question. The part of creating string worked; but while passing it in cURL command it is always failing. Don't know what is wrong.

Comment: And also please suggest whether i shall make this a gitlab question or is it fine as a general question?

Comment: @KL_KISNE_DEKHA_HAI  what does *`always failing`* mean? did you get an syntax/error message? do you get no/wrong answer? something else? as for your latest update ... I don't use gitlab nor do I understand the reference ... so I'm not sure if/how your update relates to this answer ... ????

Comment: the only thing I can *guess* at is the escaped quotes; I've removed the escaped (single) quotes and just wrapped the function call in double quotes; see if that works; if it still does not work then please update the question with an actual/real URL that you're testing against; and also include the complete output you're getting when running my answer; in order to troubleshoot I need the ability to reproduce what you're seeing

Comment: sorry man, could not tell more on this, this is organizational thing which i am working on, so apart from the question nothing else can be stated. However the error in most cases was: '{error: variables is invalid}'. Thanks anyways got an intuition based on your answer